# Highlighting/Changing the backroung colour of a text that is on a path-ADOBE ILLUSTRATOR

Tags: color, logo, background, illustrator-effects

I'm **extremely** new at graphic designing and my sister hired me to create a logo for her company.

It took a few days and I've finally perfected everything except the company name.I typed it along the path of a circle but I can't find out how to change the text background color to black and the text color to white in order to help it to pop more.

My sister loves everything else about the logo and loves the concept of the highlighting but i'm just not sure how to execute it.Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: In general you have to create an object behind the text and fill it with color. Type on a path objects don't have any background. A sample image would assist in answers.

Comment: Do you want the background colour to follow the shapes of the letters, like an outline of the letters, or to be a smooth line following the line of the path, like it's a ribbon the text is sitting on? (I thought both had been asked before here but actually I can't find either)

Comment: I want it to be like a ribbon that the text is sitting on

Comment: Thanks for all the responses but I played around with it a bit and finally achieved the outcome I was looking for.I just used the ellipse tool to create a circle,then I increased the thickness of the stroke to a little taller then the height of the letters.I then put the new circle behind the letters srung around in a circle and It turned out great!

Comment: Hi EPZ, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. If you managed to solve your problem yourself, please consider adding the solution as an answer and accepting it as the right one. This is good for the site statistics and nets you some reputation as well. Thanks! If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy your time here!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses but I played around with it a bit and finally achieved the outcome I was looking for.I just used the ellipse tool to create a circle,then I increased the thickness of the stroke to a little taller then the height of the letters.I then put the new circle behind the letters strung around in a circle and It turned out great!